# phpseclib ANSI is not displaying correctly

Tags: phpseclib

So I have a script

```
echo $ansi->getScreen();
$ansi->appendString($ssh->read());
```

And it shows:

```
������������������������������������������������������������������������������͸
```

But in putty it show:

```
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
▒0001 0002 0003 0004
```

Is there a way I can at least get it to the point where I can see the numbers?

Comment: Maybe do `echo bin2hex($ansi->getScreen())` and post the results. Or, more specifically, post them into pastebin and post the link. In lieu of having seen those there is one possibility: PuTTY emulates xterm whereas phpseclib does vt100.

Comment: I tried what you said, then converted the output back. The numbers are just missing. Is there a way to get phpseclib to emulate xterm?

Comment: Can you post the output of `echo bin2hex($ansi->getScreen())` so I can examine it? Maybe phpseclib is getting the numbers but that fact is being hidden because carriage returns are resulting in previously output data being over written. Maybe one of the ANSI escape codes isn't being parsed by phpseclib at all or maybe it is but isn't being parsed correctly. I would like to examine the data that you're passing to `$ansi->appendString` so that I might find this out for myself instead of relying on your (lack of an) assessment.

Answer (score -1):

So After investigating the issue further. Formatting coded outputted by the host machine are interacting negatively with the ANSI function. As a result ANSI is dropping information on the output.

Replacing ANSI with something of my own design resolves the issue.